# How to use google batch upload in linux

Tags: java, linux

I have read this article

http://lifehacker.com/5354441/google-docs-batch-upload-eases-online-document-transfers

```
java -jar google-docs-upload-1.2.jar /home/kevin/uploads --recursive
```

now its not working it says bas command not found.

is java already installed in vps centos or i have to install it

Comment: why don't you do a quick `java -version` or even `which java` to find it out?

Comment: I bet this is the result of Google Translate.

Comment: i tried `which java` and its empty no result. it means do i need to install it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you don't have java or its not available in your path. Some linux distros install java in the /opt directory. So be sure to check if that's the case with you. If so then its just a matter of updating your path if not then there are two possibilities :
1. You have root access.
2. You don't have root access.

If you do have root access then you can easily install java with your package manager, if now you can still install java as a local user. Read [this](http://codeslinger.posterous.com/how-to-install-java-7-on-ubuntu) to do that. You can install any version of java that you so wish, also it may be unnecessary to install JDK, just JRE might be enough for you.
Don't do the steps that need root access, just copy it somewhere in your home directory or any of the directories to which you have access. Then set the appropriate values for JAVA_HOME and your PATH. It should work then.
If you need any help in doing that feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the jar `google-docs-upload-1.2.jar`.
2. Ensure you have Java.
3. Use your **own** home- and upload-folder, not the "`kevin/uploads`" one.